# Inductive sensor and equivalent circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, sensor, inductance, proximity-sensor

I can't understand why the system depicted here:
[image]

where:

4 = permanent magnet

6 = ferromagnetic core with a coil around it

5 = ferromagnetic toothed wheel

has this magnetic circuit:

[image]
where

Rm= magnet reluctance

Rc = core reluctance

Rg = gap reluctance

Rt= target reluctance

In particular I can't understand why the MMF is written in that way. Please, consider that the parmanent magnet has a residual magnetization (and this is the reason for the subscript r in Br. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You have a variable reluctance transducer (tachometer).

The coil wrapped around an iron core is your sensor, with a reluctance \$R_c\$.  The target is your ferromagnetic toothed wheel, with a reluctance \$R_t\$.  Air gap reluctance \$R_g\$.  The total reluctance of this magnetic circuit is:

$$R_T = R_c + R_g + R_t $$

The magnetic flux \$\phi\$ produced by the magnet is applied to this magnetic circuit (OP circuit).  As the gear spins, the air gap reluctance \$R_g\$ changes, which changes the magnetic field for the coil, which induces a voltage in the pickup coil.

Basic Faraday's Law.  No spin, no change.  Rotation produces a square wave proportional to tooth speed.

[image: variable reluctance tachometer].

---

Air is a poor conductor of flux. So when tooth is close to sensor, the magnetic circuit is strengthened. When the air gap is large, the field weakens. Either way the flux experienced by the coil changes, Faraday's Law.

Take your initial circuit.  It is a magnetic circuit.  The magnet creates the magnetic flux \$\phi\$.  This flux is applied to coil with an iron core (flux conductor), the air gap and the toothed gear (flux conductor).

The tooth is iron (ferromagnetic).  Iron conducts flux about 5000 times easier than air.  So when the air gap is small the net flux becomes stronger.  The reluctance due to the air gap decreases.

Tooth rotates.  Air gap increases.  Air gap reluctance \$R_g\$ increases.  The net flux decreases.

Faraday's law says that whenever the flux linked with or associated with a circuit changes, a voltage is induced in the circuit.

The coil is a circuit (connected up to a sensor).  Flux changes and a voltage is induced in the coil.  Repeat.  Square voltage waveform will be produced in the coil sensor as coil rotates.

Stop rotation.  No change in flux.  No induced voltage.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Physically speaking, how can the wheel influence the magnetic field 'felt' by the coil if it is only a ferromagnetic material and it it not a permanent magnet? Is it due to the fact that during rotation the permanent magnet induces a FEM in the tooth and so a field resisting to the flux variation thought the tooth that produces a variation in the field 'felt' by the coil, resulting in an induced EMF?

Comment: "when tooth is close to sensor, the magnetic circuit is strengthened" Intuitively I can understand this fact, and also from a circuital point of view. But physically speaking there is something that I haven't understood yet... Is the flux variation due to the presence of the permanent magnet that induces an EMF in the thooth? Then that EMF could cause the flux variation through the coil... Many thanks for your patience! :)